# If $E(X|Y) = X$, what does this imply about the relationship between $X$ and $Y$?

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let $Z, K, V$ denote random variables, where $Z$ is binary, $K$ is categorical from 1-10, and $V$ is continuous.

Let $X = P(Z = 1|V = v)$ and $Y_k = P(Z = 1|V = v, K = k)$. Now define $Y = (Y_1, \ldots, Y_{10})$. What is $E(X|Y)$? Is it equal to $X$ because $Y$ is a coarser (or finer) partition of $X$?

My thinking is:

\begin{align*}
E(X|Y) &= E(E(Z|V=v) | \{E(Z|V=v, K=1), \ldots, E(Z|V=v, K=10)\}\\
\end{align*}

But I'm not sure how exactly to show that $E(X|Y) = X$.

Comment: The title of this question does not seem to match the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not true (in general) that $E[X|Y]=X$. Consider this example

- $X$ is sampled with equal probability from 11-30
- $Y$ is the units digit of $X$.

Then $Y$ is determined by $X$ so $E[Y|X]=Y$ but $E[X|Y]\neq X$. For example, if $Y=1$, $X$ could be 11 or 21 with equal probability, so $E[X|Y=1]=16$.

If $E[Y|X]=Y$ then $Y$ is (almost surely) a deterministic function of $X$. If that function is (almost surely) one:one then $X$ is also a deterministic function of $Y$ and $E[X|Y]=X$, but not otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. In this case, if $Y=(Y_1, \ldots, Y_{10})$ where $Y_k = P(Z = 1|V = v, K=k)$, is $X = P(Z = 1|V =v)$ a one:one function of $Y$?